# android - I can't change the ImageResource of my ImageButton

Tags: android, imagebutton, android-image

So as the title says, my ImageButton won't update its resource even though I called setImageResource.

Here is my code:

```
public static void toggleqsring() {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null, false);

    SquareButton qs_ringer = (SquareButton) v.findViewById(R.id.qs_ring);

    if (mPhoneIsSilent==0) {
        qs_ringer.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_qs_ring_off);
    } else if (mPhoneIsSilent==1) {
        qs_ringer.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_qs_ring_on);
    } else if (mPhoneIsSilent==2) {
        qs_ringer.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_qs_vibrate_on);
    } 
}
```

SquareButton is a class that extends ImageButton, but I have made its height equal to its width.

I don't know what I have done wrong here, can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got it working after a bit of experimenting.

Instead of passing the Context of MainActivity, I passed the Activity itself to a new variable

```
public static Activity mActivity;
```

And used this code to change the image resource. Since findViewById is a method of Activity but not Context, you can only do it with an Activity variable:

```
public static void toggleqsring() {

    SquareButton qs_ringer = (SquareButton) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.qs_ring);

    if (mPhoneIsSilent==0) {
        qs_ringer.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_qs_ring_off);
    } else if (mPhoneIsSilent==1) {
        qs_ringer.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_qs_ring_on);
    } else if (mPhoneIsSilent==2) {
        qs_ringer.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_qs_vibrate_on);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
qs_ringer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_qs_ring_off);
```

Comment: No that just sets my picture as the background instead, and it doesn't work.